# jQuery Color plugin didn't trigger by Selectable elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can I use the jQuery Selectable elements-

```
<div class="toggler">
        <div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Animate</h3>
            <p>
                jQuery UI bundles the jQuery Color plugins which provides color animations as well as many utility functions for working with colors.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

<ol id="button">
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
</ol>
```

to trigger Color Animation plugin instead of the button-

```
<button id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Toggle Effect</button>
```

My attempt to combine both effects wasn't successful.

```
$(function(){

    var state = true;
    $( "#button" ).on( "click", function() {
      if ( state ) {
        $( "#effect" ).animate({
          backgroundColor: "#aa0000",
          color: "#fff",
          width: 500
        }, 1000 );
      } else {
        $( "#effect" ).animate({
          backgroundColor: "#fff",
          color: "#000",
          width: 250
        }, 1000 );
      }
      state = !state;
    });

    $('#button').easyAudioEffects({
      ogg : "audio/1_matrix.ogg",
      mp3 : "audio/1_matrix.mp3",
      eventType: "click"
    }); 

     $( "#button" ).selectable();
});
```

Is it possible to use other clickable elements to make Color Animation plugin work, instead of the button?

I will appreciate any suggestions

Comment: ID should be unique. You can use class to all similar elements and bind event using class selector.

Comment: It would be prettier with css classes and transitions.

Comment: I fixed that, but it still not working when I'm using the same selector in the both plugins simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

id should be unique here id (button) is duplicated.

```
    <li id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" >car 1</li>
    <li id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" >car 2</li>
    <li id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" >car 3</li>
```

Comment: I fixed that, but it still not working when I'm using the same selector in the both plugins simultaneously. Is that some kind of conflict between plugins to use the same selector?